# Zend Skeleton Application A 404 error occurred Page not found

Tags: zend-framework

I'm new to ZF. I'm using wamp 3. I followed the instructions from the Zend Framework Documentation (https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html), installed ZendSkeletonApplication and everything worked fine until step 3 (routing and controllers) when I got the error:

> "A 404 error occurred
>
> Page not found.
>
> The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
>
> No Exception available".

I don't know what the problem is, since I **copied everything** from the tutorial on the site (so that I don't make any typo) and it still won't work.

Any suggestions what the problem might be?

module.config.php looks like this:

```
return array(
 'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
     ),
 ),

'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
         'album' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                 ),
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                     'action'     => 'index',
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 ),

 'view_manager' => array(
     'template_path_stack' => array(
         'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
     ),
 ),
);
```

I did everything as they wrote, but when I go to "myvirtualhostname/album" it shows me the error above.

Comment: What URL gives you this error? And please edit your question to include the relevant route config.

Comment: Code looks okay, so either this config isn't being used, or your module isn't being loaded. Can you check that your album `Module.php` has a `getConfig()` method, and that your Album module is included in modules array as on https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/modules.html#informing-the-application-about-our-new-module ?

Comment: Yes and yes. Module.php has getConfig() method and Album model is included in modules.

Comment: I found some additional step on https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/ . It says that I should enable development mode with "$ composer development-enable". That was not mentioned in the initial text. When tried that, I got the message "Message: A plugin by the name "getServiceLocator" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager".

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing you have ZF3 installed, but the tutorial in your question is for ZF2.4. If you're starting from fresh, follow the ZF3 tutorial instead.

Comment: Uhmmm, ok. I followed the instructions from that site I thougt that I'll get installed ZF2 not 3. Then how can I install ZF2?

Comment: Are you sure about the ZF version? Where cam I check it? Does it download ZF3 by default when i run composer create-project -n -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install? I'm pretty confuzed now. =)

Comment: That composer command installs the latest version (rather than the specific version the docs relate to). If you check your `composer.json` file, look for an entry for `zendframework/zend-mvc` - my guess is that'll have a version like `3.0.1`

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is 3.0.1. But, how can I then install 2.4.9? Can I specify somewhere the version I want to install?

Answer (score 2):

make sure you add this line (highlighted by comment) to the top of your public/index.php

```
    <?php
    use Zend\Mvc\Application;
    use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;  //<-- add this line
```

Note#1: you need to follow instructions of editing the index.php file for developing mode enabled, they just forgot to tell about using ArrayUtils in this tutorials.

Note#2 make sure to enable dev mod from the composer and dump autoload like this :

> $ composer development-enable

and then:

> [$ composer dump-autoload]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can specify the version you want to install with the initial composer command, something like this:

```
composer create-project -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application:^2.4 path/to/zf2-app
```

although you may be able to change the version on your existing skeleton app, it might be easier to run the above command in a different folder, and then copy over the files you've added or changed whilst following the tutorial.

And just to say again, unless you specifically need to learn ZF2.4, it would be better to stick with ZF3 (since that's the current version), and just follow the ZF3 tutorial instead. The differences between them are not that big.

Comment: I've listened to your suggestion and started with ZF3. I followed the tutorial and everything worked fine until I had to run it in development mode (composer development-enable). When I enable it, I get the message: " Fatal error: Class 'ArrayUtils' not found in ... on line 43". Do you have any idea how to fix this issue? Do I really need to take this step? Btw, thanx a lot for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I've not seen that error. It might be posting that as a new question (with the full error message and stack trace if there is one)

Comment: I don't know what actually happened, but I tried to enable it and disable a few times and now it finally works! =) Thanks for all the help and suggestions.

Comment: I found the error that was bothering me... In the tutorial says that index.php sholud be "<?php

use Zend\Mvc\Application;

/**
 * Display all errors when APPLICATION_ENV is development.
 */
..."
They are missing "use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;" at the begining.